# undefined reference when writing/reading Static thread_local class member?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-local-storage

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
class A{
  public:
    static thread_local long l ;
    int value ;
    A(int a = 2){
       value = a;     
    }
    int foo(){
       A::l = 3;
       return 3;
    }
};
A a;
int main(){
    // A::l = 3;
     a.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

above code on compiling gives error can someone help to resolve them? when i remove the reads and writes to static thread_local this seems to compile . does it needs some special libraries or linkers to work properly . I need to keep  static thread_local  to get same features as threadLocal class in java

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <thread>


class A{
public:
    inline static thread_local long l ;
    int value ;
    A(int a = 2){
        value = a;
        
    }
    int foo(){
        A::l = 3;
        return 3;
    }
};

A a;

int main(){
    A::l = 3;
    a.foo();

    return 0;

}

Comment: thanks a lot adding inline with g++  -std=c++17 solved problem

Comment: inline keyword worked for me, but why?

Comment: @Rajeshkumar I have the same question, how does inline keyword do the magic?